# VBA Countifs function - variable quantity of criteria

Tags: excel, vba

If i want to use countifs in a function, some times it needs just 2 critera and sometimes 3

whats the best way i could achieve this without using 2 functions , for 2 and 3 criteria.

```
Function Check(sh as worksheet, col1 as range, crit1 as range,col2 as range, crit2 as range,col3 as range, crit3 as range)

    If Application.CountIfs(col1,crit1,col2,crit2,col3,crit3) > 1 Then
        'true
    End If

End Function
```

this is just a sample to illustrate the issue

Comment: Make col2 and crit2 `Optional` arguments

Comment: i understand that part of it, but how to do that in the actual countifs statement tho?

Comment: You would need to branch on whether the second set of arguments were provided, and have two versions of the `CountIfs()`

Comment: Ok, i guess thats one option i could do!    is there a way to parse a string into countifs  like "rx,cx,ry,cy" and "rx,cx,ry,cy,rz,cz"  ? i couldnt find much online about parameters in this way

Comment: What is the point of the variable `sh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unclear on why a UDF based on the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) needing a ragged length number of parameters is necessary for a UDF  when COUNTIFS accepts a variable number of parameters itself¹ directly but I'm sure it is all part of a master plan.

```
Function how_many_do_you_want_to_count_to(ParamArray rCOUNTs() As Variant)
    Dim v As Long, sFormula As String

    sFormula = "=COUNTIFS("
    For v = LBound(rCOUNTs) To UBound(rCOUNTs) Step 2
        sFormula = sFormula & rCOUNTs(v).Address(0, 0, external:=True) & Chr(44) _
                            & rCOUNTs(v + 1).Address(0, 0, external:=True) _
                            & IIf(v < UBound(rCOUNTs) - 1, Chr(44), Chr(41))
    Next v

    how_many_do_you_want_to_count_to = Application.Evaluate(sFormula)

End Function
```

¹<sub>Up to 127 range/criteria pairs are allowed in COUNTIFS</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Check(sh as worksheet, col1 as range, crit1 as range, _
               col2 as range, crit2 as range, _
               Optional col3 as range, Optional crit3 as range)

    Dim n

    If IsMissing(col3) Then
       n = Application.CountIfs(col1,crit1,col2,crit2)
    else
       n = Application.CountIfs(col1,crit1,col2,crit2,col3,crit3)
    end if

    If n > 1 Then
        'true
    End If

End Function
```

Or similar to @JohnColeman's approach:

```
Public Function Check(sh As Worksheet, ParamArray args())

    Dim rv, f, n, num
    f = "COUNTIFS("
    For n = 0 To UBound(args) Step 2
        f = f & IIf(n > 0, ",", "") & args(n).Address(False, False) & ","
        Select Case TypeName(args(n + 1))
            Case "Range": f = f & args(n + 1).Address(False, False)
            Case "Integer", "Long", "Double": f = f & args(n + 1)
            Case "String": f = f & """" & args(n + 1) & """"
        End Select
    Next n

    num = args(0).Parent.Evaluate(f & ")")

    If num > 1 Then
        'etc etc
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bite the bullet and make `Application.WorkSheetFunction.CountIfs` more programmer friendly and allow the programmer to pass in an array rather than needing to type the arguments in explicitly. Then you could use this version in your `Check` function. The following code was (mostly) written by another VBA sub which I am not including:

```
Function VBA_CountIfs(args As Variant) As Double
    Dim n As Long
    n = UBound(args) 'assumed to be 0-based
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Select Case n:
            Case 1:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1))
            Case 3:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3))
            Case 5:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5))
            Case 7:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7))
            Case 9:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9))
            Case 11:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11))
            Case 13:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13))
            Case 15:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15))
            Case 17:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17))
            Case 19:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19))
            Case 21:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21))
            Case 23:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21), args(22), args(23))
            Case 25:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21), args(22), args(23), args(24), args(25))
            Case 27:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21), args(22), args(23), args(24), args(25), args(26), args(27))
            Case 29:
                VBA_CountIfs = .CountIfs(args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21), args(22), args(23), args(24), args(25), args(26), args(27), args(28), args(29))
            Case Else:
                VBA_CountIfs = -1 'error flag
        End Select
    End With
End Function
```

An example to show how this could be used:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print VBA_CountIfs(Array(Range("A1:A5"), Range("B1"), Range("C1:C5"), Range("D1")))
End Sub
```

(Which returns the right results for my test sheet). If you find a nice string representation of ranges you could possibly create the input to `VBA_CountIfs` using the `Split` function.

A variation of this idea would be to declare the input to `VBA_CountIfs` to be a `ParamArray`